# Slicing the image into text line using the rectangle boundary box

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I have a scanned image of a page of text of which I want to segment the lines of.
For example, using simple methods like:

- using a rectangle boundary box method
- slicing it into fixed rectangles

The size of the rectangle should be a variable which I can change manually.

I do not want to use the projection profile method as there may be touching overlapping lines.

Here I just want to experiment with this method of just slice of it using this rectangular way.

I am looking for a method of automating the process ( instead of cropping it manually )

Can someone suggest implementations and relevant materials in Matlab / Python ?

My input is one jpg image and output will be a number of images ( based on the number of lines ) and the aim is to save each segmented line ROI as as line_1.jpg, lie_2.jpg and so on.

Comment: You're mentioning a few simple methods already. You should post your attempt as a minimal code snippet explaining what doesn't work. I recommend checking out [Adrian Rosebrock's OpenCV Text Detection (EAST text detector) article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a primitive method of slicing the image into several rectangles based on a set `Line_Height`. Unfortunately, this method relies on the height of each line to be equal and the image to not be subject to large amount parallax. Text detection and other techniques may also be applied to evaluate the height of each line before implementing this code below.

[image: Slicing Image]

[image: Full Text Image]

[image: Sliced_Text_Image]

```
Line_Height = 100;

Image = imread('Tiger_Drawing.jpg');

figure(1)
imshow(Image);

[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(Image);

Number_Of_Lines = floor(Image_Height/Line_Height);

for Line_Index = 1: +1: Number_Of_Lines

Bottom_Boundary = (Line_Index-1)*Line_Height+1;
Upper_Boundary = (Line_Index)*Line_Height+1;
    
if Upper_Boundary > Image_Height
Upper_Boundary = Image_Height;
end

fprintf("(%d -> %d)\n",Bottom_Boundary,Upper_Boundary);    

Image_Segment = Image(Bottom_Boundary:Upper_Boundary,:,:);
Image_Segment_File_Name = "line_" + num2str(Line_Index) + ".jpg";
imwrite(Image_Segment,Image_Segment_File_Name);

figure(2)
subplot(Number_Of_Lines,1,Line_Index); imshow(Image_Segment);

if (Line_Index == 1)
title('Sliced Image');
end

end
```